# Magento - Change alignment of "Sort By" option box on product list page?

Tags: html, css, magento

After a bit of work I have successfully moved the "Sort By" option on the product listing page of my website from its original position up next to the limiter (for the amount of products shown on each page) without breaking it.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to change it's current alignment.

I've got it displaying inline with the limiter, but I would like to move it over to the right so it is directly next to the limiter (rather than being directly in the center as it is now).

You can see it's current position on the product listing page here:  http://soundcherry.com/index.php/sound-effects.html

How do I achieve moving the "Sort By" option to the right?  I feel like it's something incredibly obvious and I'm simply missing it due to my lack of experience.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

***EDIT***

This is the part of the styles.css page that I believe I need to change.  What do I alter exactly?  Every time I think I have it figured out, it doesn't produce the results I expect.

```
/* Sorter */
.sorter { font-size:11px; padding:1px 8px; }
.sorter .view-mode { float:left; margin:0; }
.sorter .sort-by { float: right; }
.sorter .sort-by label { vertical-align:middle; }
.sorter .sort-by select { padding:0 ; margin: 1px; vertical-align:middle; }
.sorter .link-feed {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in simple way

As i change from firebug to add 2 small property to your `sort-by` class you can add like below with inline style or in you css if you want to get same features in all pages

just add below css

```
float: right;
margin-left: 15px;
```

**EDIT**

```
   .pager .sort-by { float: right;  margin-left: 15px;}
```

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to help me.  I'm a pretty big amateur at this stuff, so I'm still having trouble getting it to work.  I've edited my original post to show the part of the style.css file that I believe deals with the sort by feature.  Which part of the code am I supposed to change exactly?